# Grant permissions to access Azure blobs from my Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure

I have a Rails application for streaming and downloading videos. A user authenticates himself through the application, and then he can choose which video to view, from the list of videos he was granted access to.

I was using AWS S3 to store the videos. With the AWS SDK I could generate URLs for certain videos and set an expiration time. This way I could, through my Rails application, decide whether a certain user can access a video, then generate a URL using the AWS SDK and render it in the view (either with a download link or through a media player).

Now, I would like to migrate to Azure (geographical reasons) but I couldn't find a good way to manage the permissions to the blobs I store. Again, I'm looking to grant access to the videos through my Rails application - without any additional log in actions on Microsoft platform and without generating permanent Azure credentials per user.

I started looking at [ACS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/gg185963.aspx) and I think that might be the solution I am looking for. However, I couldn't find any guidance on how to manage ACS through the azure-sdk-for-ruby gem. Could someone please elaborate on ACS or suggest other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described above is known as `Query String Authentication` in AWS. Similar thing in Azure Storage is called `Shared Access Signature`. You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee395415.aspx.

There's an Azure SDK for Ruby which you can find here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/tree/master/lib/azure. Please check if there is a function for creating shared access signature there.

If not, you can always use Azure Storage REST API to create the signature. You may find this link helpful for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn140256.aspx.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find the functionality in the official Azure Ruby SDK. However, it seems like there's a Ruby gem that wraps the Shared Access Signature: https://github.com/dmichael/azure-contrib
I will try using it, thanks!